# Using Mercurial extension

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have recently started using Mercurial and in the extensions list provided by TortoiseHg Workbench I found an extension called Simplelock. I am unsure on how to use this. As in I find it necessary for my project but I am unable to use this since whenever I try to click Lock Repository it gives me the error:
 **Operation aborted: No lock repository configured.**
This is probably my in-expertise talking but would someone tell me how to work around this and to use this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I've never used it but googling "mercurial simplelock" gives the docs: https://bitbucket.org/sborho/simplelock.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes I have been using that to work, but maybe I have misunderstood somewhere but it still gives me the Operation Aborted error

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the lock repository?

Initialize an empty repo where everyone on your team can access it. Everyone should clone the lock repo locally and configure their global hgrc or Mercurial.ini file with the location of the lock repo.

```
[simplelock]
repo = ~/work/locks
```

Comment: I did that and well I am getting this error now on TortoiseHg Bug Report:   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tortoisehg\hgqt\locktool.pyo", line 178, in operationComplete
      File "tortoisehg\hgqt\locktool.pyo", line 110, in refillModel
      File "hgext\simplelock.pyo", line 64, in parseLocks
    NameError: global name 'ui' is not defined

Comment: @Ren I tried the extension out and get the same error.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm unsure how to proceed from here.. Should I look for another utility or should report this as a issue and wait?